# DataGridView won't show class list column

Tags: c#, list, view, grid

Trying to display a class named Creature with the following fields in a data grid view.

```
private string _name;
private decimal _speed;
private decimal _power;
private decimal _hp;
private string _type;
private List<Weapon> _weapons = new List<Weapon>();
```

All of the fields except for the list are appearing. The `DataGridView` is using a list called `_Dictionary` as the data source. `_Dictionary` is of the Creature type and all of the data is present including the Weapon List data. Any ideas why the data grid view won't show it.

Comment: Are you using auto generated member in your `DataGridView`? (i.e. `GenerateMember = true`), if that's true, the weapons can't get shown because the `DataGridView` don't know how to show a `List<Weapon>` in a cell. What is you expecting result to be shown in the column for `_weapons`?

Comment: Also I assume you have public properties for those private field right? Since the `DataGridView` columns can't bind to private fields

Comment: Tag your question with the UI you are using, WinForms/WPF or what ever...

Answer (score 0):

DataSource doesn't take enumerable type because it doesn't know its inner property to represent values so it is better to use anonymous type and select the properties you want to show  from each instance of type

```
 dataGridView1.DataSource = _weapons.Select(Weapon=> new {Weapon._name, Weapon._speed}).ToList();
```

Comment: While this code block may answer the OP's question, this answer would be much more useful if you explain how this code is different from the code in the question, what you've changed, why you've changed it and why that solves the problem without introducing others. please read [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: @SaeedZhiany Thank You I have added a comment, it is just simple change that's why I didn't add elaboration